# Regex in Selenium Xpath Not Working //*[contains(@content-desc,"Resend in .*?[0-9a-zA-Z]*[0-9][0-9a-zA-Z].* sec")]

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, appium, appium-android

My Text in UI is **"Resend in 48 sec"** in which **"48"** is a timer which is dynamic so I want to crate an Xpath using the contains and Inside Contains I am using Regex but still unable to find the Element

`//*[contains(@content-desc,"Resend in .*?[0-9a-zA-Z]*[0-9][0-9a-zA-Z].* sec")]`

Answer (score 1):

Selenium is still using XPath 1.0, which was defined over 20 years ago and has no support for regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this XPath instead:

```
//*[contains(@content-desc,"Resend in") and(contains(@content-desc,"sec"))]
```

Now you can get this element, get it's `content-desc` attribute value and then validate the content of that attribute

Comment: It's partially correct but I want to make sure that whether Number is displaying or Not.That's the reason why I am using Regex

Comment: where do we have regex here ?

Answer (score 0):

You may wanna do this instead  :

```
String regEx = ".*?[0-9a-zA-Z]*[0-9][0-9a-zA-Z].*";
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(@content-desc,'Resend in') + '"+regEx+"'  + and(contains(@content-desc, 'sec')) ]"));
```